# Problema con sintaxis de Dlookup

Tags: vba, ms-access

me estoy volviendo loco con este código tan simple:

```
Private Sub NºLote_Click()
Dim slote As String
Dim units As Integer
slote = Me.NºLote.Text
MsgBox slote
units = DLookup("[unidades]", "[recepción materiales]", "[lote]='"&slote&"'")
MsgBox units
End Sub
```

slote es un string que es capturado correctamente (lo compruebo con el msgbox)

units es un número, que se ha de localizar en la tabla recepción materiales a través del lote, que es un string.

El editor de VBA me da error de sintaxis todo el rato, señalánome en rojo la lína del operador dlookup.

slote es un string, y está entre comillas simples en la expresión, por lo que he visto en otras preguntas, lo he puesto correctamente...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Pongo la imagen con el error, que es me indica "se esperaba separador de listas o )"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este código es correcto:

```
units = DLookup("[unidades]", "[recepción materiales]", "[lote]='" & slote & "'")
```

Revisa que los & tienen espacios en blanco a izquierda y derecha. También, aunque funcione, intenta evitar el uso de acentos en [recepción materiales]

Si te vuelve a dar error, será de otro tipo, no de sintaxis de Dlookup

Answer (score 1):

El código de tu imagen es diferente al que has puesto. Fíjate que falta un ampersand `&`.

En tu imagen sale

`units = DLookup("[unidades]", "[recepción materiales]", "[lote]='" & slote"'")`

Y debería ser como has puesto en tu pregunta:

`units = DLookup("[unidades]", "[recepción materiales]", "[lote]='" & slote & "'")`

Comment: Gracias, pero me sigue dando error una vez lo corrijo. De hecho, creo que el ampersand lo borré accidentalmente antes de hacer la captura de pantalla.

Comment: Vuelvo a poner la captura de pantalla con el error

Answer (score 0):

He logrado solucionarlo encerrando la variable slote entre paréntesis:

```
units = DLookup("[unidades]", "[recepción materiales]", "[lote]='" & (slote) & "'")
```

Un saludo

Comment: Hola, deberías marcar esto como respuesta correcta